# super.onStop() called without an explicit call from the inherited class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an abstract class which is the base class for all the activities in my app:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity { 
    // class content
}
```

In this class, I have the onStop() method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "BaseActivity- onStop()");
}
```

And, when I want to override the onStop method in a inherit activity, I do:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "LiveActivity - onStop.");
}
```

Now, the strange thing is: in every inherit activity the onStop() method from BaseActivity is called **without** calling the own onStop() method. An example from one excerpt of my logs:

```
com... D/live_activity﹕ LiveActivity - Activity onStart
com... D/live_activity﹕ BaseActivity - onStart()
com... D/live_activity﹕ BaseActivity- onStop()
```

I know that I am missing something but I can't figure what. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post some more relevant code? Can't find anything wrong with this.

Comment: Is there more in the logs below what you have posted? Nothing unusual in what we see there, in `onStop()` you call `super` first, and then log, so BaseActivity would log before LiveActivity.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 activity like activity1 and activity2 whenever you ar starting activity1 to activity2 it will perform like this

```
activit1.onpause
activity2.oncreate
activity2.onstart
activity1.onstop
activty1.ondestory
```

I hope this information will help to you :)

Comment: This is unrelated to the issue raised in the question.  Perhaps you misunderstood - the two classes the poster mentions are not distinct Activities they are switching between, rather one is a general form, and the other a specific extension of it.  The only object is an instance of LiveActivity, but some it its functionality is inherited from the code of BaseActivity, just as some of that's functionality is inherited from android.app.Activity.